# calculating rolling slope optimization

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy

I have the following function to calculate the rolling slope

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
pip install pandas as pd 
def get_slope(array):
    y = np.array(array)
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x,y)
    return slope
# apply a rolling window ad follow 
data['accl']=(data['temp'].rolling(10).apply(get_slope))

# this one works however, it takes forever to finish if you have a big data set.
```

this one works however, it takes forever to finish if you have a big data set. any ideas how to do it faster?

Thanks

Comment: How fast is `xs = np.arange(10); xs_demeaned = xs - xs.mean(); den = (xs_demeaned**2).sum(); data.temp.rolling(10).apply(lambda s: ((s - s.mean()) * xs_demeaned).sum() / den, raw=True)`? (I think putting it as an answer with explanation is better done iff speed is good enough.)

Comment: Another option is: `win = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df.temp, (10,)); ((win - win.mean(axis=1)[:, None]) * xs_demeaned).sum(axis=1) / den` if you have NumPy 1.20+.